# Can't update record in test method

Tags: apex, unit-test, lastmodifieddate

I'm trying to make a test class for an Apex class that runs a report and add functionality for it (send some emails and stuff). The **problem** is that I need to add records (contacts) for that report to work with, but I cannot make them fit the conditions required in the report.

The report conditions are: `checkbox = TRUE AND edit date = TODAY`

In the testMethod I do:

```
Contact c = new Contact(checkbox__c = FALSE);
insert c;
c.checkbox__c = TRUE;
update c;
System.debug('>>'+c.checkbox__c+', '+c.LastModifiedDate)
// run the report...
```

And this prints in the log:

```
USER_DEBUG [52]|DEBUG|>>TRUE, null
```

The checkbox its set to `TRUE` correctly but he LastModifiedDate is set to `null` when it was updated just now. The report runs correctly but says that it have not records to show and end the execution.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to query back for the record.

```
Contact record = new Contact(SomeField__c=someValue);
insert record;

record.SomeField__c = otherValue;
update record;

record = [SELECT SomeField__c, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact WHERE Id = :record.id];
system.assertNotEquals(null, record.LastModifiedDate, 'This record has been modified');
```